# can't get random # to pass through switch statement

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

So I'm trying to make a 'Magic 8 ball' generator in JavaScript. I apologize if my wording is wrong, I've just started coding a couple of weeks ago.

I'm trying to figure out why I cannot get my code to log the variable 'eightBall' from my switch statement. Below is the code that I used, and it is not logging anything to the console.

```
var randomNumber = [Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)]
var eightBall = ''

switch (randomNumber) {

case 0:
eightBall = 'Better not tell you now." ;
break;
case 1:
eightBall = 'Concentrate and ask again." ;
break;

}
```

I have 7 cases set up, but for the sake of space I don't want to type all of them out. I know for sure all of my switch statement syntax is correct.

When I console.log (randomNumber) it prints out a random number for me. But when I console.log(eightBall) it doesn't print anything out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Why is `randomNumber` an array?

Comment: That solved my problem! Thank you! I'm brand new to coding so I'm making a bunch of silly errors with the syntax currently. I wasn't sure if you needed brackets or if you could use 'parentheses inside parentheses.'